# Let admin confirm database change

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Our Symfony application makes use of Doctrine, in combination with the [EntityAuditBundle](https://github.com/simplethings/EntityAudit) to keep track of database changes. This works great for past revisions, the bundle almost exactly tells us what changes has been made.

The next problem is future database changes. Our customers are not able to change their user details, because we need to manually confirm those. Think of the following changes:

1. bank account number
2. email address
3. image of passport

**Question:** What is the best mechanism to let admins first review proposed database changes? The admin should be able to accept or decline the change.

**Subquestion:** Will this also work on Doctrine `OneToMany` and `ManyToMany` relationships?

Answer (score 1):

For an app that I just finished, I had an Audit table set up - then info was sent in an email to a list of 3 admin emails through their outlook server, and I generated a link for a quick review with an "accept" and a "decline" button.  The accept triggered a stored procedure with the Audit table's ID, copied the data to the normal table, then emailed the requesting user that the table was updated... Decline - held the data in the audit table, and forced the admin to enter a note which was emailed to the requesting user.  There were only 2-5 requests a day and it was from employees (connected internally, so you could trust the requests more than promiscuous app data).  There could be a much better way - but this method worked very well for me.  Also, the audit table kept ALL data - all requests, regardless of whether or not they were granted.  This was used for reports.

Comment: How do you handle multiple type of entities? All entities have their own audit table?

Comment: Yeah the only tables that were used were called AccountActivityLog, SalesForecastLog, QuoteLog, and BookingLog... so it was easy to maintain the audit tables with a trigger and a stored procedure